# How to sort with a delimiter that is several characters long?

Tags: sort

INPUT:

```
$ cat a.txt 
1FOO2FOO3
4FOO5FOO5
2FOO1FOO9
$
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ cat a.txt | sort SOMEMAGIC
2FOO1FOO9
1FOO2FOO3
4FOO5FOO5
$
```

**Question**: How can I sort, if I have a several character long delimiter? ("FOO")?

In the example `a.txt` is sorted by second column.

Question is in general, numbers in `a.txt` could be anything.

Comment: Maybe in this case you can sort from the 5th columns: `sort -k1.5n`

Answer (score 9):

Use e.g. `sed` to replace the string with a one-character delimiter, sort by the column, and then replace the delimiter back again:

```
sed -e s/FOO/X/g a.txt | sort -k 2,2 -t X | sed -e s/X/FOO/g
```

This assumes that there is a character that you know doesn't appear in the input. A control character would be a common candidate, but you need to make a choice based on your knowledge of the input format.

Comment: That stops working when the 'fields' contain the temporary delimiter (e.g. `2FOOXFOO9`). Of course, maybe you trust your knowledge of the input.

Comment: The person would obviously have to check the input before choosing the new delimiter.

Comment: Just use a lower ascii char that text files usually don't contain, like `\x02`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$ perl -ane '
    push @h,[$_,(split(/FOO/))[1]];
    END {
        print map  { $_->[0] }
              sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}
              @h;
    }
' file
2FOO1FOO9
1FOO2FOO3
4FOO5FOO5
```

**Explanation**

- Store each array ref [line, key] in array `@h`: `[$_,(split(/FOO/))[1]]`
- When finish reading file:

  - Sort array ref in array `@h` by key `sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}`
  - Extract the original line from `@h` and print `map  { $_->[0] }`

Comment: What's `map  { [$_->[0],$_->[1]] }` for? It looks like it returns the same two elements in each listref.

Comment: @arielCo: It's a waste line, forget to clear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your fields are numeric, GNU `sort`'s [version sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort) might help. Set the delimiter to `F` so that the trailing `OO` from `FOO` goes into field 2 and field 2 is seen by `sort` as containing values `OO2, OO5 and OO1`. Specifying version-sorting on field 2 ensures that the non-numeric prefix `OO` is ignored and output is ordered by the trailing numeric portions of field 2

```
sort -k2,2V -t 'F' a.txt
2FOO1FOO9
1FOO2FOO3
4FOO5FOO5
```

Alternately with GNU `awk`, if you tolerate the overhead of an in-memory solution:

```
awk -F'FOO' '{a[$2]=$0};END{asort(a, b, "@ind_num_asc");
for (i in b) print b[i]}' a.txt
2FOO1FOO9
1FOO2FOO3
4FOO5FOO5
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need not focus on the delimiter so much as you should the `sort -k`eys. You can specify a character range for your keys.

```
info sort
```

> ...given the input line ' foo bar', `sort` breaks it into
>        fields ' foo' and ' bar'.  The field separator is not considered to
>        be part of either the field preceding or the field following, so
>        with 'sort -t " "' the same input line has three fields: an empty
>        field, 'foo', and 'bar'.  However, fields that extend to the end of
>        the line, as '-k 2', or fields consisting of a range, as '-k 2,3',
>        **retain the field separators present between the endpoints of the
>        range**.

And as Stephane has commented, this also applies vice-versa - you can sort on only a slice of a field with a byte range, and even on multiple slices of the same field with multiple keys. So in your case you can use the same field with different ranges multiple times. See?

```
sort -k1.5n -k1.1n --debug <<\DATA
1FOO2FOO3
4FOO5FOO5
2FOO1FOO9
DATA
sort: using simple byte comparison
sort: leading blanks are significant in key 1; consider also specifying 'b'
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
sort: key 2 is numeric and spans multiple fields
2FOO1FOO9
    _
_
_________
1FOO2FOO3
    _
_
_________
4FOO5FOO5
    _
_
_________
```

That instructs `sort` to sort on the primary key beginning with the 5th byte in field 1 and extending to field 1's end, and secondarily to sort from the 1st byte in field one to field one's end. The `--debug` option is very helpful when trying to sort `sort`, as I hope the above demonstrates. But here it is without debug:

```
sort -k1.5n -k1.1n <<\DATA        
1FOO2FOO3
4FOO5FOO5
2FOO1FOO9
DATA

###OUTPUT###
2FOO1FOO9
1FOO2FOO3
4FOO5FOO5
```

If you wanted to `sort` only a single character for each you'd need to close your ranges. In the above example `-k1.5n` works from byte 5 to field end because the key specification works like:

```
 -k[begin field].[first byte in key],[end field].[last byte in key]
```

So, while the results are identical for this case, you can close each field range on the same byte with which you open it like:

```
sort -k1.5,1.5n -k1.1,1.1n
```

and thereby only `sort` by a single byte for each key.